# How to fix IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer

Tags: python, select, boolean, row

I'm taking only 4 countries from a dataset of all countries at the Olympic Games.

For two datasets I could extract only the relevant countries, but when I do it for this dataset I get an error.

'''import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

table2008 = pd.read_html('https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medaillespiegel_van_de_Olympische_Zomerspelen_2008')[0]
print(table2008)
dfPeking = DataFrame(table2008)

dfPeking = (df_2008.loc[df['NOC'].isin(['NED', 'BEL', 'GER', 'FRA'])])
dfPeking
'''
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I didn't manage to reproduce your error, but by replacing the last line of the error message:

```
dfPeking = (df_2008.loc[df['NOC'].isin(['NED', 'BEL', 'GER', 'FRA'])])
```

by:

```
dfPeking = (table2008.loc[table2008['NOC'].isin(['NED', 'BEL', 'GER', 'FRA'])])
```

dfPeking looks as follows:

```
   Plaats       Land  NOC  Goud  Zilver  Brons  Totaal
4       5  Duitsland  GER    16      10     15      41
9      10  Frankrijk  FRA     7      16     18      41
11     12  Nederland  NED     7       5      4      16
36     37     België  BEL     2       0      0       2
```

Which I suppose is what you wanted to get at the end ?